# cursor jumps to top of table after row delete

Tags: javascript

In win7 vs2013 asp.net, using javascript and callbacks, I fetch, build, and dynamically add a row to a table.  This row contains an input field and "accept" and "cancel" fields.  The input field receives focus.  I press the cancel button in the row to cancel the operation.  The cancel function (javascript) identifies the row index and performs a table.deleteRow(index).

All good, except, at that point, in IE 11, the page "freezes" and the cursor is left blinking at the top  left most point of the table.  This does not happen in Chrome.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the focus on an element after the deletion occurs, either the one before or after.  Doing this will correct the problem.  What is happening is after you delete an item that is focused, IE does not know where to set the focus so it defaults to somewhere outside of the document or at the top of the document.

Comment: That was it, thanks!  There was no "logical" place to send the focus so I made a 1px text input field in the header and sent the focus there, worked slick.  Now that I have the solution I can figure out where else to send focus if needed.

Comment: That's pretty good! Instead of creating an input field you can also just set the tabindex of any element to -1 and set focus to it.  Either way is fine though!

Comment: Great tip.  Works nicely.  Thanks much!